# iOS, LaunchImage Apple Watch size and name

Tags: size, xcode6, filenames, watchkit, apple-watch

I using xcode 6.2 beta for creating app for apple watch.
I want add 2 **LunchImage** for Apple Watch **38 mm** and Apple Watch **42 mm**.
when i Adding the Images , xcode give me the error for name of **LaunchImage** or error for size 449 x 449 or 136 x 170.
i want the exact name and size for **LaunchImage** Apple Watch 38 mm and 42 mm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icons have a circular mask automatically applied to them.  You will need icons with diameter 29, 80, and 172 pixels for 38 mm and diameter 36, 88, and 196 for 42 mm.

So create images 29x29, 80x80, 172x172, etc.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/IconandImageSizes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014992-CH16-SW1

Comment: Thanks i want 196 pixels 172 pixels